# What sort of programming environment is the Pyxis/Verivo Mobile system?

Tags: mobile, cross-platform

I just heard that a company I do work for may be bringing in the Pyxis Mobile application development system.  When I google it most of what I find is from the company's web site and that is not very informative from a geek perspective.  Can any one shed some light on what sort of programming environment it is and what programing language is involved (please let there be a text based language). Any additional information would be great.

Note: the company/product changed their name to Verivo in January.

Comment: +1 - good question. I can't find anything that seems vaguely objective or impartial about this stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full Disclosure - I work as an engineer at Pyxis Mobile. However, I have been in the mobile space for 7+ years and have evaluated several approaches to mobile so hopefully this is helpful.

Pyxis Mobile provides a set of tools and components to build cross platform mobile applications. Let me outline them first.

**1. Application Studio** - All application development, backend integration, user provisioning and application maintenance/debugging is done w/in this tool. Application Studio (for now) is a Windows based desktop app.

**2. Application Clients** - Pyxis Mobile provides native client runtimes for iPhone, iPad, BlackBerry, and Android devices. These runtimes get branded for the customer through a build service and are primed to point to a specific Application Server URL.

**3. Application Server** - Pyxis Mobile App Server runs on the .NET stack (on IIS). All client communication is proxied via this server. This server is able to connect to varied of  backend systems (via the Plugin Framework listed below) and respond to the client in a mobile optimized manner. This server needs a SQL Server (2005 or newer) for configuration access, session management, logging and more.

**4. Plugin Framework** - The Plugin Framework is a backend component that provides system specific pre-built access to several of the enterprise and cloud based systems (Oracle, Siebel, SAP, Salesforce.com, social feeds, REST/SOAP web services, etc.) and also offers an API layer in .NET and Python (using IronPython) to allow even further customization. A plugin is essentially comprised of one or more DLLs or a Python file. These assets are then dynamically loaded to normalize communication between Pyxis Mobile and the customers' backend systems.

**5. Push Services** - This provides a cross-platform push layer that can poll a backend system for change and alert a mobile device via BlackBerry Push, Apple Push Notification Services (APNS) or Android's Cloud to Deice Messaging (C2DM).

**6. OverWatch Analytics** - This is an optional (but included) component to track users/devices and provide integrated analytics on what the users are using and what kind of devices and locales makes up your users.

The application itself is "coded" via configuration that is build in App Studio. Pyxis Mobile abstracts away from the code so that you can work at a higher level without having to worry about the wide array of device variances (GPS, touch screens, camera, accelerometer, push, screen resolution, etc.). You can drag fields onto a from, connect screens via menus or buttons, set up caching rules and more in this graphical utility. This configuration (essentially think of an XML like document) is interpreted by the native client layer to produce a rich application. There is also a scripting layer in Lua that allows to really customize behavior via code.

The real value of Pyxis Mobile comes up when you have change to make. The clients check for new configuration at app startup or if the server forces the client to get new configuration. This gives you great agility. Lets say once your application is deployed you want start using the swipe gesture to go next/prev through a set of records. This change on other platforms would mean writing some platform specific code to trap and interpret the swipe to perform a navigation (you couldn't trap a swipe on a non-touch screen). However, in Pyxis Mobile this is a simple configuration change that can be quickly deployed to the App Server and the clients automatically download and use the new configuration. No compilation, no redeployment or re-download for the end users.

I could keep going, but hope this provides some level of guidance.

Comment: Thank you for the disclosure. So basically you can write plugins in .Net or Python and you can tweak the overall app produced in Lua and/or configuration?

Comment: That's correct. 

However, note that Pyxis Mobile is not a code generator. The Admin Studio produces mobile optimized configuration that the native clients download and interpret. The Lua code is also downloaded with the configuration (or bundled ahead of time in case of iOS) which allows to tweak several aspects of the application.

Answer (score 5):

Beware of Pyxis Mobile.  While many of the things they say do work, there are some serious platform issues (as a geek) which I've experienced.

1) No version control system process.  The Application studio can basically only be developed on by one person at a time or you risk having your changes overwritten by a fellow developer.  The "principle of last save" is very much in play.

2) No unit test coverage.  This isn't the biggest issue for a lot of people, but it's a concern for anyone who wants to work in the Enterprise world.

3) The middleware server gets you some value, but it's also a PITA to work with.  There is no concept of "client side storage" unless you consider the middleware server the client side.  If your phone goes out of coverage, your app won't work.  Again, this might not be an issue for you.

4) The application has no true scripting language to work with.  The middleware server allows you to intercept requests and responses and modify what you're doing there, but it's not the most elegant solution considering that a native application can have something as simple as "if this then X else Y."  This can be accomplished with Pyxis, but the whole process is convoluted and more complicated than one would think it needs to be.

5) Lack of documentation.  There's some training guides and the GUI is easy enough to get around for simple apps; however, when you need to do something with guts, you're left relying on Pyxis professional services.  There's really no developer community to pose questions to.

I have more complaints, but they are more opinion oriented than Q/A oriented.

Comment: Thanks for the other view on this. We are still gathering data and it was a little disconcerting that I only got one reply to the question.

Comment: My biggest turnoff is probably the lack of freely available information.  Pyxis could improve their position by hosting some sort of developer forum which would allow users to "swap secrets."  Of course, I'm not entirely sure there's all that many customers to swap secrets with.  It's my understanding that Pyxis does not have very many companies that develop their own applications.

Comment: +1 Thanks for posting this critique. My company is also toying with the idea of Pyxis, but the absence of any developer community is making me really apprehensive. I love their runtime and deployment model. However, the lack of a programming language - only GUI configuration - bugs me as well. I couldn't find anything on details of security either. The Pyxis PR says it's secure, but I'd like to know what is being sent over the wire, how clients are authenticated, how secure is the storage on the device etc? Their whole pitch is at managers and not developers which makes me nervous...

Comment: The data is encrypted on their middleware tier and encrypted when sent to and from the device.  I'm told the 7.3 development platform is almost ready to be shipped out, but I haven't seen it.  Supposedly it covers some of the issues I brought up, but certainly not all of them.  Honestly, at this point, my biggest concern is the lack of developer community.  I can't tell you how frustrating it is to deal with a programming issue that NO ONE other than their support team can help me with.  No google assistance, no stackexchange, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I just got note about the most recent comments. I don't want to turn this into a thread of back and forth, but did want to throw a couple of quick notes.

Regarding the points on version control and documentation/developer community - no big contest there. We are definitely working on these shortcommings. We have some basic pieces in place, but we have big plans to focus on this.

Regarding unit testing - we provide a very open interface to our middleware and backend components and they can be very easily unit tested with a bit of instrumentation. We run a ton of unit and integration tests internally. However, mobile unit testing is extremely difficult to get right. We'll investigate this further.

Regarding #4 around middleware and offline capabilities - things are a lot different now. With version 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3 our products have increasing become more capabale offline and now features a secure local database if necessary. I can provide more details as necessary, but you can certainly login and operate the app even if you are out of coverage for weeks at a time!

Regarding #5, we've had a scripting engine for over 2 years. Its Lua based and its actually quite powerful and fast. It was BlackBerry only till the most recent release. Given Apple's [change of stance](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/06/11/apple_relaxes_ios_sdk_to_allow_lua_but_block_flash.html) on allowing scripting we now allow scripting on BlackBerry, iPad, iPhone and Android as well now!

@RockMeetHardplace - feel free to reach out to me directly and I'll be happy to give you more detailed live demos of our latest platform. I am at - arunSPAMNOTatpyxismobiledotcom (drop the "SPAMNOT" and replace the at and dot). I happen to be the Director of Software and interested in knowing more about the issues you had.